# How to locate element using css selector or id which contain "-" in id and attribute?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have tried for by css selector. It gives an error unable to locate element.
                  `<a id="First-name" class="nav-link js-open-add-panel p-y-sm w-full" data-toggle="tab" data-target="#previous-9" data-href="#current-9">`

Comment: Can you add the HTML,the code and the full error message to your original question. That will help us to answer your question.

Comment: Please share what you have tried, and explain us what you want to achieve .

Comment: Your _code trials_ and _error stack trace_ please.

Comment: You can use this CSS :- `#First-name`